# RDS Provisioned IOPS got limitation?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, provisioned-iops

I originally have my MySQL setting to 500 GB and 5000 IOPS. It has a write IOPS limit to 3500.

Later on, in order to boost the IOPS performance, I decided to upgrade the MySQL setting to 1.2 TB with 12000 Provisioned IOPS. However, it seems I am still bounded to 3500 Write IOPS limit.

I have a very heavy usage on one single table which store many user information and data. The Read IOPS is very low and less than 100.

Is there anything I have done wrongly or configured wrongly such that my write IOPS is limited?

Answer (score 0):

Please ensure the following:

P1) You have very good EBS-Optimized Instance types for your PIOPS volumes. if you have XLarge instances they come with 1000 Mbits and you can do ~120 MB/s transfer to your EBS.  Sometimes this becomes a bottleneck.

P2) You have pre warmed your EBS volumes and you are maintaining the queue depth 1 per 200 IOPS

P3) Use EBS Striping for better write performance. But i dont think you can use all your 12K IOPS for write operations alone, i have observed usually it is 6000 IOPS for writes for 12K IOPS.

What file system are you using ?

Comment: Does your answer relate to RDS? Or MySQL on EC2? Other than having the right instance selected, can you achieve the P2, P3 configurations when using RDS?